# Java array turning to zeros after exiting a for loop

Tags: java, image-processing, multidimensional-array, fft

I'm using an FFT class I found online to compute the FFT of an image. Here's the code to compute the FFT.

w (width) and h (height) are the same value in this instance.

```
FFT2 fft = new FFT2(w);
double[] realRow = new double[w];
double[] imagRow = new double[w];
double[][] realVals1 = new double[w][h];
double[][] imagVals1 = new double[w][h];

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
    {   
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            pixel = bmporiginal.getPixel(x, y);
            R = (int) (Color.red(pixel));
            G = (int) (Color.green(pixel) );
            B = (int) (Color.blue(pixel));

            I = ((R+G+B)/3);
            I *= Math.pow(-1, (x+y) % 2.0 );
            realRow[x] = I;
            imagRow[x] = 0.0;
        }
            fft.fft(realRow, imagRow);
            realVals1[y] = realRow;
            imagVals1[y] = imagRow;
    }
```

The values I need are being stored in realVals and ImagVals. I can print these values within the for loop and get good values. After leaving the for loops I print them again, and get nothing!!! What could be the problem? I appreciate your help!

Comment: have you tried to declare them globally and try the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reusing the same row arrays for *every* iteration of the loop.

So at the end of the two loops, your `realVals1` and `imagVals1` will each have `h` references to the same array. You need to create a new array on each iteration of the outer loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
{   
    double[] realRow = new double[w];
    double[] imagRow = new double[w];

    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
    {
        ...
    }
    fft.fft(realRow, imagRow);
    realVals1[y] = realRow;
    imagVals1[y] = imagRow;
}
```

Additionally, I believe your declarations for `realVals1` and `imagVals1` are a) inefficient and b) the wrong way round. I suspect you want:

```
double[][] realVals1 = new double[h][];
double[][] imagVals1 = new double[h][];
```

You're going to be replacing the elements anyway, so there's no point in populating a bunch of empty rows...

Comment: This is what's up! Thanks for your help. I will select this as the answer when it allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

You're reusing the same array realRow and imagRow each time through the inner loop.  Since Java works with references, when you assign realVals1[y]=realRow, you assign a reference.  Since you always use the same array, you assign all the rows to the same array reference.  Which is not what you want.  You need to recreate realRow and imagRow to a new double[] at the top of the outer for loop.